# Not able to download file in external directory in Android 10

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to use Cordova plugin to download files in an external folder. Here is my code

```
const writeFile = (path, filename, blob)=> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (dirpar) {
            dirpar.getDirectory(path, { create: true }, function (dir) {
                dir.getFile(filename, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                        fileWriter.onwriteend = () =>{
                            console.log("Successful file write...");
                            console.log("=========================");
                            console.log("=========================");
                            console.log("=========================");
                            console.log("=========================");
                            console.log("=========================");
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
                            console.log(fileEntry.fullPath);
                            return resolve
                        }
                        fileWriter.onerror = reject
                        fileWriter.write(blob);
                    });
                }, reject);
            }, reject);
        }, reject);
    });
}
```

The error I am getting in the android studio is as follows.

```
ypersign.cordova D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10153; state: DISABLED
2021-02-26 17:01:33.775 10648-10715/com.hypersign.cordova W/AssetFilesystem: Asset manifest not found. Recursive copies and directory listing will be slow.
2021-02-26 17:01:33.812 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x888f0
2021-02-26 17:01:33.813 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f8991000 size 0x8a000
2021-02-26 17:01:33.820 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x888f0
2021-02-26 17:01:33.820 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ee8b4000 size 0x8a000
2021-02-26 17:01:33.822 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x888f0
2021-02-26 17:01:33.822 296-358/? D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ee82a000 size 0x8a000
2021-02-26 17:01:33.923 529-2448/system_process D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 149924527; UID 10153; state: ENABLED
2021-02-26 17:01:33.924 529-2448/system_process D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 132649864; UID 10153; state: DISABLED
2021-02-26 17:01:33.932 1550-1997/com.google.android.providers.media.module W/MediaProvider: Forgot to handle a top level directory in getContentUriForFile?
2021-02-26 17:01:33.940 1550-1997/com.google.android.providers.media.module E/MediaProvider: insertFileIfNecessary failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory download not allowed for content://media/external_primary/file; allowed directories are [Download, Documents]
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:2682)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureUniqueFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:2347)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2957)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3486)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:3208)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFileForFuse(MediaProvider.java:6655)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFileIfNecessaryForFuse(MediaProvider.java:6742)
2021-02-26 17:01:33.948 10648-10648/com.hypersign.cordova I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(113)] "Uncaught (in promise) #<FileError>", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js (113)
2021-02-26 17:01:34.302 1408-1463/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/PeriodicStatsRunner: PeriodicStatsRunner.call():180 call()
2021-02-26 17:01:34.303 1408-1463/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/PeriodicStatsRunner: PeriodicStatsRunner.call():184 No submit PeriodicStats since input started.
2021-02-26 17:01:35.807 529-641/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.hypersign.cordova token=android.os.BinderProxy@a738d83
2021-02-26 17:01:35.813 529-641/system_process I/NotificationService: cancelToast pkg=com.hypersign.cordova token=android.os.BinderProxy@a738d83
2021-02-26 17:01:35.813 529-641/system_process W/NotificationService: Toast already cancelled. pkg=com.hypersign.cordova token=android.os.BinderProxy@a738d83
2021-02-26 17:01:37.285 529-569/system_process W/WindowManager: Unable to start animation, surface is null or no children.
```

You can observe following issues

`Uncaught (in promise) #<FileError>`

Any help regarding this would be great

**Update**

In my config.xml file, I have the following code.

```
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,cache, sdcard, cache-external, files-external" />
```

This is how I am calling the above function

```
writeFile('download/hypersign', fileName, blob)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('File Downloaded sucessfulley')
    showToast('File Downloaded sucessfulley')
    resVal = true

  })
```

Thanks

Comment: add this line in your manifirst file inside application tag  = android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: `allowed directories are [Download, Documents]` So put your file there instead of root of external storage.

Comment: @milanpithadiacan I have updated the question I already have that

Comment: @blackapps can you please check my update I was already saving in the downloads folder

Comment: `'download/hypersign'` It should be `'Download/hypersign'`. But... Who will create that hypersign directory? Try with 'Download' only. If that works then put the hypersign in the file name parameter too.

Comment: Weird thing is it's able to create the folder Hypersign but it's not able to store the file. And this exact code worked int he Android 9 :)

Comment: It looks as if the plugin uses the mediastore to write the file looking at the error message.

Comment: @blackapps I tried with the capital ```Download``` but same error. Perhaps I should try creating the file before writing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229249/discussion-between-vikram-anand-bhushan-and-blackapps).

Comment: @milanpithadia I am going to try with this ``` <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
            <application android:requestlegacyexternalstorage="true"/>
        </edit-config> ```